# Windows 7 sees all Ubuntu partitions as primary

Tags: partitioning, windows-7

I got a new laptop with Windows 7. I resized the windows partition and installed Ubuntu 10.10 in the free space using manual partition, with several partitions for `/boot`, `/`, `/home`, swap, and another to be formated as NTFS to share files with the Windows 7 boot.

All worked perfectly on the Ubuntu side, but the disk management of Windows 7 sees all partitions as Primary and doesn't let me format the one I set aside for NTFS.  I always thought that there could only be 4 primary partitions, so seeing 9 primary partions was unexpected.  With all my previous computers this worked fine and I could use both systems to access the common data partition.

Windows 7 Disk Management:
[image]

How can I format this partition to NTFS?

---

Edit:  This is the output of fdisk -l

```
Disco /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 38913 cilindros
Unidades = cilindros de 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificador de disco: 0x949ef5d2

Dispositivo Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/sda1               1           5       40131   de  Utilidad Dell
/dev/sda2   *           6        1918    15360000    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3            1918        8258    50931829+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4            8259       38914   246238209    5  Extendida
/dev/sda5            8259        8271       97280   83  Linux
/dev/sda6           36969       38914    15624192   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7            8271       14350    48827392   83  Linux
/dev/sda8           14350       16781    19529728   83  Linux
/dev/sda9           33321       36969    29296640   83  Linux
/dev/sda10          16781       33320   132852736   83  Linux

Las entradas de la tabla de particiones no están en el orden del disco
```

The partition 10 that I wanted to be NTFS appeared as of Linux type, even when in the installer i didn't select that.  I tried changing that to NTFS with the Disk Utility and it stalled changing it.  Installed GParted but every time I run it, it crashes with

```
glibmm-ERROR **: 
unhandled exception (type std::exception) in signal handler:
what: basic_string::_S_create
```

Finally changed the type with fdisk to 0x07.  The output of fdisk changed only in this line

```
/dev/sda10          16781       33320   132852736    7  HPFS/NTFS
```

Now Windows 7 shows this partition and only this partition as being inside an extended partition.   Is there a way to validate my partition table as correct?

Comment: This is properly not the best place to find out why Win7 claims that all partitions is primary... it is not possible when using a DOS partition table (defacto standard on consumer computers that doesn't run BSD)

Comment: Can we get the output of `sudo fdisk -l`, please?

Comment: Esta es la salida de fdisk -l
http://pastebin.com/nqSNXiqA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the NTFS partition in Linux, if this will work on the windows side i don't know. But this command should be able to format the disk correctly:

```
sudo mkntfs -L "LABEL" /dev/NTFS-DISK
```

Where NTFS-DISK should be replaced by the right partiotion and LABEL replaced by a filsystem label of your choosing, you have to have the `ntfsprogs` package installed. Afaik you should then be able to (if you are a superuser/administrator) assign the partition a drive letter in Windows after formatting it.

Comment: After formating the partition i accessed it and GParted ran and showed me all the partitions.  Still, if someone known how to verify that the partition table is correct, i would appreciate it.

Comment: If Gparted doesn't complain about a corrupt partition table then everything should be good, of course it doesn't necessarily mean that windows will work (although it should!)

Answer (score 1):

To work around this Windows bug I always use the graphical partition editor [gparted](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gparted) [image: Install gparted]  (not installed per default, but available on the live CD).

As always when editing partitions: Don't forget to make backups first!

Answer (score -2):

I've always worked around this problem: Install Windows first, or install it on a separate hard drive. Simply install Ubuntu afterwards, or ensure the disk containing your Ubuntu install has the highest boot precedence in your BIOS, and rerun GRUB `update-grub`.